# Uploading files to server

Tags: c#, exception, webclient, file-upload

I am trying to upload a file from my Windows application to the server into a particular Folder using C#. However, I am getting an exception:

> "An exception occurred during a WebClient request".

Here is my code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < dtResponseAttach.Rows.Count; i++)
{
  string filePath = dtResponseAttach.Rows[i]["Response"];

  WebClient client = new WebClient();
  NetworkCredential nc = new NetworkCredential();

  Uri addy = new Uri("http://192.168.1.4/people/Attachments/");
  client.Credentials = nc;
  byte[] arrReturn = client.UploadFile(addy, filePath);
  Console.WriteLine(arrReturn.ToString());
}
```

What could be the reason for this exception?

Comment: Have you looked at the InnerException or queried the Exception stream for more info.

Comment: Yeah, I agree.  "An exception occurred during a WebClient request" doesn't tell us a whole lot

Answer (score 0):

If you are not filling in the `NetworkCredential`, then I'm pretty sure you should not attach one.

Another possibility, is that you are going through a proxy, and would need to add the proxy details:

```
WebProxy p = new WebProxy ("192.168.10.01", true);
p.Credentials = new NetworkCredential ("username", "password", "domain");
using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
{
  wc.Proxy = p;
  ...
}
```